# How do I turn off slow motion in the iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I don't know if it's because I'm using a Mighty Mouse or what, but I keep accidently turning on Slow Motion when using the iPhone simulator. How the heck do I turn it off?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pre beta 5 it was tripple shift. Apple changed (or broke it) see [this question](https://devforums.apple.com/message/68736#68736) (which doesn't have an answer).

Comment: As of today, Xcode 8.2.1, the way to toggle Slow Animations is (CMD ⌘) + T

Answer (score 20):

Updated: `version 11.3` (2019 Dec) works fine.

I have iOS Simulator `version 8.3` (Xcode 6) and the new shortcut is <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle "Slow Animations"

Answer (score 5):

I just installed "slowmo", as mentioned above, and it works on the 3.2 simulator. It took me a while to figure out how to enable it. You have to check "simulate hardware keyboard" in the simulator's hardware menu, and then press your Mac's shift key 3 times in rapid succession to toggle it on/off.

Comment: I didn't have to download anything, it just worked right out of the box. (Running 4.0.2)

Answer (score 4):

I think, In iOS 8 and above, it's <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure, but I notice toggeling 'demo mode' in the menu sometimes does the trick, and sometimes does not.  I'm also not totally sure if there actually is a slow motion feature, or if that is a bug in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can download "slowmo" from http://mschrag.github.com/ to re-enable the slow motion feature, allowing you to toggle between modes.

I tested it on the iPhone Simulator 3.1 (139.1) and it still works.

Run the slowmo.sh script in the download, then press shift 3 times in quick succession.